# Вопрос по WebBrowser

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы определенный html-файл, мог открываться только через созданный на форме WebBrowser,но не мог открываться через IE?

**Добавление.**

Использующиеся в проекте html-файлы сделаны так, что открываются только в IE, остальные браузеры априори не могут отобразить ее содержание. Но проблема в том, что я хотел, чтобы пользователь мог открывать ее только в моей программе. Поскольку WebBrowser имеет движок IE, запретить отображать html-страницу через IE я уже не смогу?

Comment: @grotsun Для уточнения вопроса правильно редактировать вопрос или добавлять уточняющий комментарий вместо создания уточняющего ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно все :) !
Открыть можно и в IE - но при этом IE должен показать херню вместо того, что покажет наш WebBrowser.

Делается все просто. Придумываем простенькое шифрование.
Самое простенькое ))) ... Шифруем страницу.

Далее, описываем это шифрование в нашей c# проге... т.е. делаем дешифратор.
Далее, НЕ WB получаем контент, а .. с помощью открытия сокета и создания необходимого запроса к Web серверу.получаем запрос, дешифруем -> заливаем в WebB.

Итого - у нас html страница открыта в WebBrpwser, а обычный Ослик должен при аналогичном запросе показать непонятную хрень :)

P.S. - не голословно. У меня так сервер лицензий пашед :)... Только вот шифрование там далеко не ламерское :)

Comment: А можно об этом по подробнее:
"а .. с помощью открытия сокета и создания необходимого запроса к Web серверу"

Answer (score 1):

Точно не уверен получится ли это, но попробовать стоит. Воспользуйтесь правами доступа к файлу. Нужно запретить доступ на чтение для IE, а для приложения, использующего WebBrowser, дать все полномочия.

Answer (score 1):

можно через `navigator.appName`

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то страничка будет отображаться только в определенном браузере. Но в компоненте WebBrowser движок IE.

Answer (score 1):

Измените информацию об агенте в вашем приложении, которая отсылается на сервер, и сможете отфильтровать остальные браузеры, хотя, конечно, это тоже не панацея, если захотят, откроют. Можно еще зашифровать весь трафик между сервером и клиентом известным только вам алгоритмом.